# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""-StringBuilder

Tags: java, stringbuilder

The main goal of the program is to find the sum of extracted dollar amount in a given String/ find the sum of only number which is appended after the `$` sign and the sum result should be from the input taken is 50040. The `StringBiulder` Object is coming in each loop but when I am trying to convert it to `toString` and trying to add it to the sum, getting the error.

required is convert the result to a number and add it to the sum that is not happening and I am getting the error:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

My code:

```java
package com.example.demo;

public class DemoApplication2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        long sum=0;
        String str = new String("#1 Tickets $50,000 Received $40. Expenses. ChequE.");
        char chararray[] = str.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < chararray.length; i++) {
            StringBuilder someString = new StringBuilder();

            if (chararray[i] == '$') {
                for (int j = i+1; Character.isDigit(chararray[j]) || chararray[j] == ',' ; j++) {
                    if (Character.isDigit(chararray[j])) {
                        someString.append(chararray[j]);
                    }
                    i=j;
                }
                
            }
            System.out.println(someString.toString());
            sum=sum+Long.parseLong(someString.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Getting the below Error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
        at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.base/java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:702)
        at java.base/java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:817)
        at com.example.demo.DemoApplication2.main(DemoApplication2.java:27)
```

Comment: Okay, so what have you done to diagnose the problem? Have you stepped through the code in a debugger? Presumably it's not actually appending anything, but we don't know what the input is or what you were expecting to end up in the StringBuilder, or what your actual aim is, which makes it hard to help you.

Comment: See https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ for a guide to asking a good question, with more details than "here's the code, here's the exception".

Comment: Think about what happens if you encounter a character that is not `$`, e.g. right at the start of your input there seems to be a `#` character. What should `ss` contain in that case? Do you expect `Long.parseLong(ss)` to work here?

Comment: On a side note: your inner loop only would append digits to `someString` so `s.trim()` shouldn't be necessary. However, think about what would happen with your second currency value `$40`. What would `someString` contain if the rest of your code would work and you'd hit the character `4`?

Comment: your someString is empty.  This means that the if statement if Character.isDigit() is false.

You are probably just starting to learn Java, put a lot of System.outs everywhere :)

Comment: my bad i dint set te context of the program, in the first place when i asked the question, got these many replies. It was asked in interview as a technical coding program. tried many thing still the issue persist with the error. if someone can help and send me the code on to where i need to put the sum and somestring statement to get the sum

Comment: @SusanMustafa, i did lot of System.outs. still getting the same error . want to get rid of the Exception

Comment: What is the sum supposed to be?  For the input String "#1 Tickets $50,000 Received $40. Expenses. ChequE.", is the answer supposed to be 50000 + 40 which is 50040?

Comment: yes  it is need to ignore the digits too which are appended with any other character apart from $ sign @GilbertLeBlanc

Comment: Hi @GilbertLeBlanc, still my question holds, what is the issue with my code, what is the reason I am getting the Exception when doing stringbiulder.tostring(). just want to understand if stringbiulder behaves that way or somewhere i am missing something. your program is fine and it applies totally different logic, i am just curious what is wrong with my program i want to get the sum in the program i have written

Comment: "What is the issue with my code"  I have no idea.  I wrote working code almost two weeks ago and haven't looked at your code.  Generally, you parse a `String` one character at a time, ideally never looking back towards the front of the `String`.

Comment: sure let me  check @GilbertLeBlanc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the result of one of my tests.

```
The sum is 50040
```

One way to do this is to go through the `String`, checking for a dollar sign.  When you find one, you set a boolean switch to true.

If the boolean switch is true, you get the next characters until you get to a stop character (period or space).  I made the assumption based on your code that the number values would all be integer values and not floating-point values.  Otherwise, you would use a `Double` conversion and a `double` sum.

I ignored the comma character and collected the digit characters into a `StringBuilder`.  I converted the `StringBuilder` digits into a `long` value.

I put the stop characters into a separate method to document what they represent.

I put the `StringBuilder` to `long` conversion into a separate method because I execute that code twice.  Once when I detect a stop character and once at the end of the `String`.  I check at the end of the `String` in case a number value is at the end of the `String` with no stop character.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
public class DemoApplication2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long sum = 0;
        String str = new String("#1 Tickets $50,000 Received $40. Expenses. ChequE.");
        char chararray[] = str.toCharArray();
        
        boolean isNumber = false;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < chararray.length; i++) {
            if (isNumber) {
                if (chararray[i] == ',') {
                    continue;
                } else if (Character.isDigit(chararray[i])) {
                    builder.append(chararray[i]);
                } else if (isStopCharacter(chararray[i])) {
                    sum += valueOf(builder);
                    isNumber = false;
                }
            }
            
            if (chararray[i] == '$') {
                isNumber = true;
            }
        }
        
        sum += valueOf(builder);
        System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
    }
    
    public static boolean isStopCharacter(char c) {
        return c == ' ' || c == '.';
    }
    
    public static long valueOf(StringBuilder builder) {
        long value = 0L;
        if (builder.length() > 0) {
            value = Long.valueOf(builder.toString());
            builder.delete(0, builder.length());
        }
        
        return value;
    }

}
```